# Axis2 in eclipse Luna

Tags: apache-axis, eclipse-luna

Is Axis2 compatible with Eclipse luna. I tried to configure it by following some articles but its not working. I copied the plugins:

```
axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

in eclipse dropins folder still not able to see the Axis2 preferences in webservice.

Comment: Have you restarted Eclipse?

Comment: Hi Garry, Yes I have restarted but its not working. All the blogs i checked are using eclipse helios. No uodates after that. Is there any compatibility issue?

Comment: can you try stable releases like 1.6.2?

Comment: No for 1.6.2 also its not working

Comment: I tried too and cant see it, however my Eclipse was already acting weird so not sure.

Comment: plz update if you come up with any solution. By the way thanks buddy for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 is not working with luna 4.4.0. I changed eclipse luna 4.4.0 to Luna 4.4.2 and its working fine for me. May be some compatible issue with Luna 4.4.0 version.